# how and where to use/set collection in an asp.net core webapi?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I need record some temporary data of each client. I don't wish use database because I think collection is fast and these data don't need save for long time.

where I should set the collection? I don't know, in an asp.net core sever, how to make an collection class has a life cycle as long as the host， and can be visited by different controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [IMemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.imemorycache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1).

**ConfigureServices**:

```
services.AddControllers();
```

**Controller**:

```
private IMemoryCache memoryCache;
public YourController(
  IMemoryCache memoryCache)
{
  this.memoryCache = memoryCache;
}
```

**Access**:

```
protected static string CacheKey = "UniqueCacheKey";

public static List<YourObject> GetCachedYourList(IMemoryCache cache)
{
    if (cache.TryGetValue(CacheKey, out List<YourObject> cachedList))
    {
        return cachedList;
    }

    // otherwise populate your value from database
    // var yourCachedList = ...
    cache.Set(CacheKey, yourCachedList, TimeSpan.FromDays(14));
    return yourCachedList;
}
```

For more details, check out the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-3.1):

Comment: thanks for your reply. And does asp.net core allow set an Concurrent dictionary and share it between different controller?

Comment: in wpf/uwp, I can set a collection in app class and it can be shared in almost the whole application. If I want to do like this, what should I do in asp.net core sever ?

Comment: Yes, you can access the same cache from multiple controller by using dependency injection of `IMemoryCache` in each of these controllers.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can I understand like this, in asp.net core, use DI to share object between different endpoint, the way  replaced global variable as a better choice?

Comment: DI can be used to share object between controllers and even the same object. Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1 for further reference. Have a look at `Singleton`